# Tails in my Windows 8 UEFI

Tags: windows, tails

I would like to know how can I run Tails in my windows 8 UEFI.
I have a Tails usb that works in my windows 7 (64), but when I put my usb in win 8, my computer does not start on usb, my screen switch on/off already.
Do you have an answers for me?

Comment: In booting the Windows 8 machine, get the boot-device list, and see if it contains both legacy and UEFI devices. If it shows just UEFI devices, you'll need to create a UEFI-bootable USB.

Comment: hello and thanck you.when i look on my start, i have got only UEFI and i can't start whith another OS. i try with ubuntu, kubuntu, tails... but it dont work! I hate Win 8.

Answer (score 1):

You can not boot using windows8 BIOS. Go into setup and disable fastboot and then go other option and change BIOS type to Legacy or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not OS-dependent, it's how the hardware works. You need to examine the following in your BIOS(it may need updates if you have an old one):

- **Is the legacy boot enabled?** If not, the USB drives will not be among the list of the devices that are searched at the very first phase of the boot-up process to look for an operating system *loader*
- **Is your boot drive list locked?** It's a secure habit to leave *just one* drive to boot from - to avoid some attack vectors. Make sure that you have checked the previous part and that the drive is in the boot list
- **What is your BBS key?** BBS states for an explicit list of *every* boot-capable device that a BIOS can see. The boot device priority list has a size of 3 or 4 items like in a half of the times, so there can be just no turn for your USB drive to be checked: a common situation is a fully unlocked list but 3 devices are HDD, CD/DVD and an Ethernet card, but the BBS menu allows you to choose the drive explicitly and it will work. Uually it can be F8, F10 or F2(if it's not used for the BIOS itself)
- **Secure/Signed boot enforcement** It can ruin your day if your BIOS allows you to boot only specifically signed *bootloader*, like NTLDR. Turn it off and Save changes in BIOS, after that you can see your device in all the lists including BBS menu if this was an issue
- **UEFI boot** To boot *any* Linux you don't need it, usually&actually, most of the times. So - if the problem still persists and the UEFI can be disabled(usually the alternate mode is called as *Legacy boot* or *MBR boot*) - give it a try.